# Conditionally apply ui-mask on a field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For a masking such as this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ssn" ui-mask="XXX-XX-9999" model-view-value="true" ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="#" />
```

How to go about adding that mask conditionally? Something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ssn" if(dataType == "SSN") {ui-mask="XXX-XX-9999" model-view-value="true" ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="#"} />
```

dataType possible values are "TEXT, PASSWORD, SSN, PHONE, NUMERIC" etc.

Comment: why don't you use ng-if?

Comment: Can we use the whole `ui-mask="XXX-XX-9999" model-view-value="true" ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="#"` string inside `ng-if`?

Comment: i don't think so it would break the dom instead you should use multiple input with ng-if so that one would appear at a time, its the best practice

Comment: yes, that's my final go-to approach (separate input fields) but I was hoping I could do it in a single one